# get a list of liked videos by user using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app on windows phone 8, using the facebook graph api.
for that, i need, for a particular user, all the youtube video posts that he/she has liked ever, but I haven't succeeded till now, in doing this.

in what way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find "[FQL/Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like)" useful for this.

Comment: I tried this:
SELECT user_id,object_type,object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()

but its not working !

Comment: did you gave user `read_stream` permission? C'mon you "love to explore new tech stuff" :)

Comment: :) yup, I have the permission..
actually above line is working...but

SELECT user_id,object_type,object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_type="video" is not giving me any results

Comment: ya tried that not giving me either. I haven't use this, so i can help me till here only. I've reported this bug

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT user_id,object_type,object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_type = 'list' instead. Try it in FQL query explorer, and you will see that 'list' are all video results.